# error connecting to linux server from windows client

Tags: python, mongodb, connection

When a windows machine pings to linux server to run application specific python commands, it does connect. The firewall is also disabled on linux server. mongodb is database server here. database is on same server. Not sure if this ascertains smooth relation between deadline api and database. Any views ?

```
from DeadlineConnect import DeadlineCon as con
data = con("xx.xx.xx.xx", 8082)     # this give a data object
print data.Groups.GetGroupNames()   # but this gives error, httplib.BadStatusLine: No status line received - the server closed the connection
```

The system throws urllib2.URLError [Error 10061] - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tried,

```
data = con("xx.xx.xx.xx", 2049)    # this give a data object
print data.Groups.GetGroupNames() # but this gives error, httplib.BadStatusLine: No status line received - the server closed the connection
```

Is it an issue with connection between deadline server and db server. They are both on same machine. By some sense this should not be causing this issue. But is that a certainty. Not sure. Please share your views ~

Comment: You're getting an error back from the server, so the netwok is not blocking you. This might be better suited to StackOverflow. It looks like maybe you're trying to talk to something that is an HTTP service but you're not talking HTTP?

Comment: @shearn89 I'd read the error message as that the connection was dropped at the IP layer, not application layer.

Comment: @nish what does `curl http://ip-address:8082/` return? Please [edit] your post with this information.

Comment: @vidarlo - maybe, that error literally means the server responded with an HTTP code that wasn't understood though... So enough connection to establish a TCP connection but not wrong protocol.